# How to make cbind or merge not create duplicate entries?

Tags: r, merge, xts, rbind

I start with this data:

```
a <- xts(order.by = Sys.Date()-1:5,(6:10))
b <- xts(order.by = Sys.Date()-5:10,(10:15))

merge(a,b)
           a  b
2019-04-05 NA 15
2019-04-06 NA 14
2019-04-07 NA 13
2019-04-08 NA 12
2019-04-09 NA 11
2019-04-10 10 10
2019-04-11  9 NA
2019-04-12  8 NA
2019-04-13  7 NA
2019-04-14  6 NA

rbind(a,b)
             [,1]
2019-04-05   15
2019-04-06   14
2019-04-07   13
2019-04-08   12
2019-04-09   11
2019-04-10   10
2019-04-10   10
2019-04-11    9
2019-04-12    8
2019-04-13    7
2019-04-14    6
```

Notice how the entry and value of 10 at 2019-04-05 is duplicated. I would like to avoid a remove duplicates method and have it done as part of the merge operation if possible.

The desired output would be just like the rbind version but without the duplicate entries.

```
           [,1]
2019-04-05   15
2019-04-06   14
2019-04-07   13
2019-04-08   12
2019-04-09   11
2019-04-10   10
2019-04-11    9
2019-04-12    8
2019-04-13    7
2019-04-14    6
```

In this case the values for the date are the same, but if they are not I should be able to choose which one I want.

Comment: `unique(rbind(a,b))`?